# Overriding trait functions with different types in Scala

Tags: scala, class, polymorphism, traits

I have the following:

Classes "Hashtag" and "Keyword" EACH extend trait "Data"

Classes "HashtagManager" and "KeywordManager" EACH extend trait "DataManager"

These have identical functions, except the types they manage (hashtags/keywords) are different.

HashtagManager has one List[Hashtag] and KeywordManager has one List[Keyword]

I'd like DataManager to implement a function findInList(X), where X is either a Hashtag or a Keyword.

How can I write the *entire* function implementation in a generic way in DataManager while leaving the TYPE of X to be changeable when it is overridden in HashtagManager/KeywordManager?

Also, how can DataManager have a generic var of List[X], where upon overriding this var in each of the subclass managers, it becomes List[Hashtag], List[Keyword], respectively?

Comment: What have you already tried by yourself? Code?

Comment: It's a very simple function, that basically searches the list and finds the given element. But that's irrelevant. I'm just wondering how to write the implementation of the function in the trait itself, and simply override that same function in my subclasses.

Comment: @ethereumbrella one thing writing it as code does it clarify your question. As is, it is a little ambiguous

Comment: what do you want `findInList` to do?

Comment: My apologies, I haven't written any code yet because I'm new to Scala, thus my reason for this question. Instead of findInList(), how about addToList(X), which will simply add X to the List[X] that's in the enclosing class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your situation is like

```
trait Data
class Hashtag extends Data
class Keyword extends Data

trait DataManager {
  // need a List[Data]
  // need a findInList(x: Data)
}
class HashtagManager extends DataManager
class KeywordManager extends DataManager
```

If you want the lists to start empty, you could ...

```
trait DataManager[T <: Data] {
   var l: List[T] = List.empty[T]
   def findInList(x: T) = ??? // not sure what you want to find
}
class HashtagManager extends DataManager[Hashtag]
class KeywordManager extends DataManager[Keyword]
```

If instead you want to initialise your lists l on class instantiation, you could ...

```
trait DataManager[T <: Data] {
   var l: List[T]
   def findInList(x: T) = ??? // not sure what you want to find
}
class HashtagManager(var l: List[Hashtag]) extends DataManager[Hashtag]
class KeywordManager(var l: List[Keyword]) extends DataManager[Keyword]
```

The crucial part is `[T <: Data]`, which then allows you to define your methods/vars/vals using a type `T` (that inherits from `Data`)